# Build an Android app with Bazel and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, bazel

How can I use OpenCV Android SDK in Bazel ?

[This tutorial](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/tutorial/android-app.html#add-an-android_library-rule) explains, among other things, how to [Add an android_library rule](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/tutorial/android-app.html#add-an-android_library-rule) and how to [Add an android_binary rule](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/tutorial/android-app.html#add-an-android_binary-rule)

Which one I have to use in the case of OpenCV android sdk and how ?

Answer (score -1):

You might find this helpful (also contains a GitHub link to the workspace, bazel and build files): https://plus.google.com/+ChristopherBlay/posts/SkJXqa4QGH6